# XSL using Xpath Returning up the tree to get an attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

getting stuck on this one..

have stripped back some stuff here to make it smaller as i doubt you need to see 150,000 lines of xml.

```
<Report>
<item id="1">
<vsection>
<hsection>
<component id="26">
<stuff1></stuff1>
<stuff2></stuff2>
<stuff3></stuff3>
</component>
</hsection>
</vsection>
</item>
</Report>
```

Obviously there is a lot more in that XML but i am highlighting the key points i am at  node #26, of item #1. I have searched via my XSLT (v1.0) to get to that point and now i need to go back up and identify which item[@id] is of that component i am at.

very short current XSL: (ingnore case differences i know about that)

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="report/item" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Report/Item">
<xsl:if test="Properties/DrwQty &gt; 1">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="VSection/HSection/Component" mode="drawers"/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="VSection/HSection/Component">
<xsl:variable name="DisplayName" select="DisplayName" />
<xsl:if test="IsPresent[text()='Yes'] and contains($DisplayName, 'Order')">
    <ID><xsl:value-of select="../../../*[@id]"/></ID>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The "../../../*[@id]" keeps returning to me all answers of all nodes all the way back down the tree. I just need to get the single answer of the attribute of the Item node, anyone able to help explain this to me?
if i replaced to xsl:value-of select="@id" i get the answer "26" which is the current attribute of the Component node :(

Cheers,
Alistair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<ID><xsl:value-of select="../../../@id"/></ID>
```

or:

```
<ID><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::Item/@id"/></ID>
```

Note:
1. XML is case-sensitive; you can't "simplify" your input by changing the case.
2. Square brackets are a notation used to indicate a  *predicate*.

Comment: Thank you Michael, the second option is the one i ended up using and was perfect. (with regards to the case, i was rushed but realise that in order to make it actually work i was going to be case sensitive)

Comment: Michael.Hor, can you help clarify something so i understand it fully, is the "ancestor::Item/@id" is the ancestor any ancestor level of the parent node? ie an ancestor of the ancestor, or just plain ancestor. and is the "::" meaning 'find an ancestor that has a node 'Item' / with and @ attribute = "id" is that the correct intepretation of the code?

Comment: Ancestor is an ***axis*** leading from parent to grandparent to great-grandparent etc. all the way up to the root element. The xpath `ancestor::Item` means "*an element named 'Item' found on the ancestor axis*". The xpath `ancestor::Item/@id` means "*an attribute named 'id' of the above element*" (regardless of whether such attribute exists or not).

Comment: Thanks very much for the clarification Michael.hor257k.

Answer (score -1):

If you are getting all id instead of one you should use predicate:

```
**<ID><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::item[1]/@id"/></ID>**
```

Comment: This would make sense only if a Component had more than one ancestor Item.

Comment: Yes, you are right. There might be a possibility user has multiple item ancestor.

Comment: Thanks guys, in reference to Component to Item, each Item may contain multiple Components, but each Component was only going to belong to one Item. Good to know the alternative in case its the other way around however.